# Why does Calendar.get() set a previously unset value?

Tags: java

It appears that Java's Calendar.get()-Method has the habit of changing a Calendar's property when being used on unset values.
Example:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Spielwiese {
    
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.clear();
        System.out.println(
                "initially: isSet == " + cal.isSet(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "\n" +
                "asking for value anyway: " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "\n" +
                "now changed: isSet == " + cal.isSet(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
initially: isSet == false
asking for value anyway: 1
now changed: isSet == true
```

Why should it be acceptable for a get-method to change any object's properties?

Comment: Well, try out the newer java.time package instead.

Comment: To expand a bit on @JustanotherJavaprogrammer's comment: `java.util.Calandar` is a poor API, and has been recognized as such for a long time. The `java.time` package is basically "calendar version 2", and fixes a bunch of issues. So the short answer to your "why" question is: "probably for no good reason, and whoever wrote that code probably regrets it now". (Time and calendar stuff is generally a lot harder than people first assume, so it's not surprising that "version 1" didn't get everything right.)

Comment: I guess I will go with the comments from "Just another Java programmer" and @yshavit . Still frustrating, but not worth the effort to ponder on legacy API.

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) of `get()`: "*Returns the value of the given calendar field. ... The normalization and validation are handled by the complete() method, ...*", `complete()`: "*... Then, the computeFields() method is called to calculate all calendar field values.*" and `isSet()`: "*Determines if the given calendar field has a value set, including cases that the value has been set by internal fields calculations triggered by a get method call.*" (as mentioned above, "a poor API")

Comment: @user16320675 Please make an Answer of your Comment so that we can mark this Question as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know "why should it be acceptable for a get-method to change any object's properties", but it is working as documented:

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) of `get(int)`:

> Returns the value of the given calendar field. ... The normalization and validation are handled by the [complete()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#complete()) method, which process is calendar system dependent.

And of `complete()`:

> Fills in any unset fields in the calendar fields. ... Then, the [computeFields()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#computeFields()) method is called to calculate all calendar field values.

Also relevant, [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#isSet(int)) of `isSet(int)` (emphasis mine):

> Determines if the given calendar field has a value set, **including cases that the value has been set by internal fields calculations triggered by a get method call.**

---

Please note that the `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, `java.text.DateFormat` and similar (sub-classes) were outdated by the `java.time` package (and sub-packages) in Java 8 (2014!) - it is recommended to use the new classes!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I switched my code to `java.time` and it was totally worth it! The new code is more compact and more intuitive. Usually I hate it when for a question "how can I make A work" the answer is "you shouldn't do A, B is much cooler (I think)", but in this case it is very appropriate.